# CMD to determine a 'Public Network' in active networks

Tags: cmd

I am trying to figure out how to determine when an active network is Public.  Is there a way to pull this through WMIC, or CMD prompt to actually display "Public" as a status?  netstat doesn't seem to give me what I want, IPconfig does not show 'public'.  I tried Get-NetConnectionProfile in Powershell, but no luck :(

> The term 'Get-NetConnectionProfile' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>
> At line:1 char:25
>
> - Get-NetConnectionProfile <<<<
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-NetConnectionProfile:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Any ideas?

Comment: *I tried Get-NetConnectionProfile in Powershell, but no luck :(* What exact problem you experienced?

Comment: Get-NetConnectionProfile : The term 'Get-NetConnectionProfile' is not recognized as the name of 
a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a 
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-NetConnectionProfile
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-NetConnectionProfile:String) [], CommandNotF 
   oundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: OS? PowerShell version?

Comment: Win 7 64, Powershell ISE v1.0

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer for you!

This uses PowerShell and WMI to obtain your answer.  I've tested on machines with both Domain and Public internet settings (don't have any private networks, sorry)

```
     Get-WmiObject MSFT_NetConnectionProfile -Namespace root/StandardCimv2 | 
       select Name,@{n='ActiveNetworkProfile';e={
         switch ($_.NetworkCategory){
             0 {'Public'}
             1 {'Private'}
             2 {'Domain'} 
             Default {$_.NetworkCategory}
            }
          }
        }
```

Running this gives you the following output:

[image: You can have multiple connections, but still only one firewall profile will be active.]

If you want to know simply what the Active Profile is, pipe the above into `Select -Unique ActiveNetworkProfile` which will give the following output.

[image]

Comment: If you're curious how I found the answer, I [used this post](https://yoursandmyideas.wordpress.com/2014/12/30/decompiling-powershell-cmdlet-code/) to figure out how to decompile a PowerShell cmdlet.  I then decompiled the Get-NetConnectionProfile cmdlet to look at the WMI classes it was querying.  Fun!

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting Get-WmiObject : Invalid namespace "root/StandardCimv2"
At C:\Temp\powershell\commoncommands.ps1:700 char:1
+ Get-WmiObject MSFT_NetConnectionProfile -Namespace root/StandardCimv2 |
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObj 
   ectCommand

Comment: Oops, I just noticed that this WMI namespace only exists in Windows 8 and up.  Short answer?  What you want will be very, very difficult to obtain in windows 7, if it is even possible to find at all.

Comment: appreciate the attempt.